# Авто отправка готового css кода по FTP

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, scss, ftp

Есть gulp файл для преобразования scss кода в css:

```
// Основной модуль
import gulp from "gulp";
// Импорт путей
import { path } from "./gulp/config/path.js";
// Импорт общих плагинов
import { plugins } from "./gulp/config/plugins.js"

// Передаем значения в глобавльную переменную
global.app = {
    isBuild: process.argv.includes('--build'),
    isDev: !process.argv.includes('--build'),
    path: path,
    gulp: gulp,
    plugins: plugins
}

// Импорт задач
// import { copy } from "./gulp/tasks/copy.js";
import { reset } from "./gulp/tasks/reset.js";
// import { server } from "./gulp/tasks/server.js";
import { scss } from "./gulp/tasks/scss.js";
import { js } from "./gulp/tasks/js.js";
import { ftp } from "./gulp/tasks/ftp.js";

// Наблюдатель за изменениями в файлах
function watcher() {
    // gulp.watch(path.watch.files, copy); // gulp.series(html, ftp)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.scss, scss); //gulp.series(scss, ftp)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js, js);
}

// Основные задачи
// const mainTasks = gulp.series(fonts, gulp.parallel(copy, html, scss, js, images));
const mainTasks = gulp.series(scss, js);

// Построение сценариев выполнения задачи
const dev = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, watcher);
const build = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks);
const deployFTP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, ftp);

// Экспорт сценраиев
export { dev }
export { build }
export { deployFTP }

// Выполнение сценария по умолчанию
gulp.task('default', dev);
```

Только по команде `npm ftp deploy` отправляется готовый css код на сервер, хочется он работал по умолчанию, когда что-то поменяю в scss.

По команде `gulp`, работает watcher и все сразу собирает в один css и наблюдает за изменением‥ также хотелось добавить отправку сразу готового css на сервер.

Не знаю, правильно ли объяснил?